# Fieldmask in proto2

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm working on a project where I'm manipulating Google Protocol Buffers objects, with Protobuf v2 specs. I need to implement a sort of a Fieldmask to let only the allowed fields (defined by a path / set of paths) to stay in the object, or the other way around, to trim all fields and their values given a map of paths.

A library exists in proto3 https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.field_mask_util
But I didn't find something similar in proto2.

My first question: is there's any library or a proper way to do that?

If not, I will have to build this, but for that, is there any way to get a path given a descriptor? (and it can be more complicated if there's also indexes a.b[0]... etc)

Do you have any other strategy to suggest?

Oh. last but not least, I need to handle this in C++

thank you

Comment: The internals of the proto2 and proto3 C++ library are mostly shared. Maybe you can look into the source code to see how the proto3 version does it, and do the same?

Comment: I don't see anything in that library's docs that indicates it only works for proto3 - and it would be very unusual, since the generated code is mostly the same, with even a common superclass for all messages.